# Pictures with isobaths to a 3D Model in a Browser

Tags: qgis, 3d, svg, bathymetry

I have pictures of lakes with isobaths (*). The result should be a 3D model in a browser.

I tried to make a vector image, but this results in a SVG. I can not import it.

How do I make a layer of the images with the isobaths? Which format is needed?

I know how to get from the layer / map with contour lines to a 3D model using Qgis2threejs.

(*) I also have data from one (Lowrance) plotter of many lakes. Can I import such data files and get a layer?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to the GIS Stack Exchange! If you haven't yet, please make sure you take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with the Q&A format we try to follow here. When asking a question, always try to give as much information as possible so that other users can address your question without asking for clarification. For instance, you mention "pictures"; could you please tell us the format of the data, perhaps include a screenshot or information about its source?

Comment: I'm not clear which direction you're trying to go with this data. Are you stuck trying to import it into QGIS? Or are you having trouble exporting from QGIS into a format your browser can understand?

Comment: I want to import the picture with the isobaths into QGIS. The method, how I can get a 3D format for a Browser I know. It means: "I stuck trying to import it into QGIS".

Comment: How can I set attributes (depth) to the different "polygones"?